# IOS images in TableView is there any way to improve performance

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, swift3

I have a tableView that is populated by Json. One of the fields returned has the full URL to the image that it needs to download . I do that and everything works however sometimes as I am scrolling down you see the wrong image in a TableView row then it changes back after 2 seconds and this happens after I see about 12 or 13 images then it starts to get slower . I would like to correct that. The code I have so far is this .

**stream_image_string**: It has the full path to the URL of the image

**var Stream_Cache = NSCache()** : caches images

The code below is inside the TableView -> UITableViewCell

again everything works the way it's supposed to, just wondering if I can get better performance .

```
    // if more than 0 then it has a URL 
   if stream_image_string[indexPath.row].characters.count > 0 {
        if let image = Stream_Cache.object(forKey: stream_image_string[indexPath.row] as AnyObject) as? UIImage {
            cell.stream_image.image = image
        } else {
            if cell.stream_image != nil {
            let strCellImageURL = self.stream_image_string[indexPath.row]
            let imgURL: NSURL = NSURL(string: strCellImageURL)!
        let request:NSURLRequest =  NSURLRequest(url: imgURL as URL)
        let config = URLSessionConfiguration.default
        let session = URLSession(configuration: config)
      cell.Stream_Image_Height.constant = 400
        let task = session.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest,    completionHandler: {(data, response, error) in
            DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: { () -> Void in

                if data != nil {
                cell.stream_image.image = UIImage(data: data!)
                } else {
                     cell.Stream_Image_Height.constant = 0
                }


            })
        });

        task.resume()
            }
    }
    } else {

        cell.Stream_Image_Height.constant = 0
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set the image to a placeholder (instead of nil) and use prefetching (see WWDC'16 session 219) to start fetching for your images earlier:

```
    protocol UITableViewDataSourcePrefetching {
       func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, prefetchRowsAt indexPaths: [NSIndexPath])

    optional func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cancelPrefetchingForRowsAt indexPaths:
    [NSIndexPath])

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The image downloading is probably fine, what you need to do is implement:

```
override func prepareForReuse() {
     stream_image.image = nil
}
```

Inside your cell